# Design of ESC for bldc motor having encoder

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Is it possible to vary the speed of propeller or BLDC motor from maximum value to minimum value per cycle of rotation. I mean blade accelerated per half cycle and deaccelerated per next half cycle. What is the design criteria of ESC for this operation? To change the high speed low speed region on rotational plane I think encoder are necessary. How can it achived through a closed loop control? Any suggestion will be helpful for me

Comment: I think you need to do a lot more research into what a BLDC motor is, and also that question needs to be re-written to ask something clearly.

Comment: ... and this sounds more like an application for a stepper motor anyway.

Comment: As crazy as it sounds, could be cyclic control for single-bladed helicopter :)